# Inside glow on textfield in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, textfield

I have a textfield that has a kind of transparent background with border and then some kind of glow on the inside that makes it pop.
I need help as I don't know how to achieve this glow. I have tried wrapping the textfield in a container with a linear gradient, but it only makes the glow appear at one edge.
Here is a picture of what I have currently and what I want, side by side.

left is what I have, and the right is what I'm trying to achieve
[image: screenshot of two textfield, left is what i have and the right is what i'm trying to achieve]

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to add inner shadow with blur. Use BoxDecoration in Container and tweak spreadRadius and blurRadius as per your need.

```
Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.blue[500]!,
                ),
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.blue[900]!,
                  spreadRadius: -5.0,
                  blurRadius: 5.0,
                ),
              ],
            ),
            child: TextField(
              obscureText: true,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: Thank you very much for replying. I was able to adjust the numbers on your code and i got something similar.